# Fit the content inside the screen whatever the screen size is - Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my page, I have a header, a footer and a container `id="item"` containing a list of four items and their logos. I'm trying to fit the `item` container responsive based on the screen size so that the whole page always fits the screen and I don't have to scroll whatever the screen size is.

But I'm not sure how to make the `item` container responsive including their logos based on the screen size. I've tried several options but none of them seems to work perfectly.

This is what I've made so far. Thanks in advance for your suggestions:

And here is this is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ashonko/aq9Laaew/974/).

```css
html,
body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 background: #66B34E;
 color: #efefef;
}

.container {
 max-width: unset;
}

.title {
 background: #187be1;
 padding: 20px;
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 11px;
 color: aliceblue;
 bottom: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin-top: 7px;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.list {
 max-height: 60%;
 max-width: 100%;
}

.menu {
 background: #f8f8f8;
 border-radius: 0;
 box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
 padding: 20px;
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 11px;
 color: black;
 bottom: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.footer {
 position: fixed;
 box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #434A54;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 12px;
 padding-top: 7px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container title"><br>This is the header<br><br></div>
<div class="container list" id="item">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-6 menu"> <img src="https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png"/> <br>
            Item 1
         </div>
         <div class="col-6 menu"><img src="https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png"/><br>
            Item 2
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-6 menu"><img src="https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png"/><br>
            Item 3
         </div>
         <div class="col-6 menu"><img src="https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png"/><br>
            Item 4
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="container footer"><br>
   This is the footer<br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're `#item` should already be responsive to the window. Try adding

```
#item img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: #66B34E;
  color: #efefef;
}

.container {
  max-width: unset;
}

.title {
  background: #187be1;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: aliceblue;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.list {
  max-height: 60%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.menu {
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: black;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#item img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #434A54;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-top: 7px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container title"><br>This is the header<br><br></div>
<div class="container list" id="item">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 menu"> <img src="https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png" /> <br> Item 1
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 menu"><img src="https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png" /><br> Item 2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 menu"><img src="https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png" /><br> Item 3
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 menu"><img src="https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png" /><br> Item 4
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container footer"><br> This is the footer<br>
</div>
```

Comment: I think it might be  `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` which he didn't include

Comment: @Sylent - true, but he didn't include the `<head>` either, so it's kinda hard to tell.

Comment: Well, @Ghostrydr and @Sylent, I've got that meta name inside my `<head>`. And yes, this answer works fine only the problem is, it responds to the changes in the width of the screen, but when the height of the screen changes, the `item` doesn't respond.

Comment: try adding `max-height:100%;` to that class as well

Comment: @Ashonko - Are wanting your `#item` to fill the space between your header and footer?

Comment: @Ghostrydr, yes, I want the whole page to always fit the screen so that I don't have to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

In order to obtain a full size `#item` container you should switch `.container` for `.d-flex`. `.container` has some `padding` and `max-width` set by default in Bootstrap that `.d-flex` does'nt have.

You can also add the class `img-fluid` to all your logos and make them fit in their container.

I add those corrections to the fiddle.

```css
    html,
body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 background: #66B34E;
 color: #efefef;
}

.title {
  align-items: center;
 background: #187be1;
  height: 80px;
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 11px;
 color: aliceblue;
 justify-content: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin-top: 7px;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.list {
  height: calc(100vh - 187px);
  background: red;
 }

.menu {
 background: #f8f8f8;
 border-radius: 0;
 box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
 padding: 20px;
 font-size: 11px;
 color: black;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.footer {
  color: white;
  align-items: center;
 position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
 box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #434A54;
 justify-content: center;
 font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="d-flex title"><br>This is the header<br><br></div>
<div class="list d-flex align-items-stretch row" id="item">
         <div class="col-6 align-items-center d-flex menu">
         <figure>
         <img src="https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png" class="img-fluid"/> <br>
            Item 1</figure>
         </div>
         
         <div class="col-6 align-items-center d-flex menu">
         <figure>
         <img src="https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png" class="img-fluid"/><br>
            Item 2</figure>
         </div>
         
         <div class="col-6 align-items-center d-flex menu">
         <figure>
         <img src="https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png" class="img-fluid"/><br>
            Item 3</figure>
         </div>
         
         <div class="col-6 align-items-center d-flex menu">
         <figure>
         <img src="https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png" class="img-fluid"/><br>
            Item 4</figure>
         </div>
         
      </div>
<div class="d-flex footer">
   This is the footer
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't solve the problem that when the height of the window changes, the `item` size doesn't respond.

Comment: If you want to consider the height of the window and your header and footer have fixed height you can calculate it.
I have updated the fiddle to adapt the width and height of the main container. Then you can adjust the CSS to match exactly with how you want your #item to act.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your desired result with display: table and display: table-cell properties. Try this code.

```
<li class='navUsernameLi'>
<div class="inner">
  <img class='navProfilePicture' src='http://via.placeholder.com/350x150'>
  <p class='navUsernameP'>Username</p>
  </div>
</li>

.navUsernameLi {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.inner {
  display: table;
}

.navProfilePicture {
  display: table-cell;
  border-radius: 50px;
  vertical-align: inherit;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.navUsernameP {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```